# El Capitan's Spotlight internet features are not working. e.g. it's not showing weather for my location

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have already restarted Mac 5 times and it did not work. My Mac is connected to the internet as I am posting this over the internet. I updated my Mac today and now it's running El Capitan 10.11.5

[image]

The first thing I did is to look at the Spotlight feature of El Captian "Weather Search from spotlight" but it did not work (to much disappointment).

[image]

I have checked the Spotlight preferences and everything there is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As [this Apple Support page states](http://www.apple.com/osx/feature-availability/#spotlight-suggestions), Spotlight suggestions doesn't seem to be available in your region.

*It's pretty surprising since you are using it en English, but I already had the same experience (OS X is in French, but those features aren't available since I am not in the French mainland).*

Comment: Thanks for replying @trevior but I will be waiting for a workaround. However, +10 for the nice information.

Comment: You are welcome! From what I saw, connecting from an IP located in supported countries seems to work, but that's not a really good solution. (And than you for the vote)